# Jquery, dynamic checkbox selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown list with different categories which i've setup like this:

**Main1**
sub1
sub1
sub1

**Main2**
sub2
sub2
sub2

etc.

When I press on "Main1" all "Sub1"s will be checked, and so on.
I have made a function that works.

```
$('.main_check_1').change(function() {

        var checkboxes = $(".check_1");

        if($(this).is(':checked')) {

            checkboxes.prop('checked', true);

        } else {

            checkboxes.prop('checked', false);

        }
    });
```

but only if I hard code it, it doesn't work dynamically.

(On my admin page i'll be capable of adding more and give them an id, Main"1", Sub"1" etc).

Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: Can you show the `HTML`?

Comment: Can you fiddle this...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the mains a unique classname, you could give them a unique id-name instead and a non-unique classname, for instance 'checklist'. Make sure the classnames of the subs are the same as their parent-main-id. Now you can make something like:

```
$('.checklist').change(function () {
    var mainCheck = this;
    $("." + mainCheck.id).each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', $(mainCheck).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qepcv8df/1/)

Answer (score 0):

changing your code into following might help

```
$(document).on('change', '.main_check', function() {
    var mainCheck = $(this),
        subChecks = mainCheck.children('.sub-check');

    if(mainCheck.is(':checked')) {

        checkboxes.prop('checked', true);

    } else {

        checkboxes.prop('checked', false);

    }
});
```

Just make use of "on" method.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful - **notice how I Managed the HTML**:

```
$('#main_check_1').click(function() {
this_box = $(this);
        var checkboxes = $('.check1');

    checkboxes.each(function(){
        checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
        if(this_box.is(':checked')) {

            checkboxes.prop('checked', true);

        } else {

            checkboxes.prop('checked', false);

        }
    });

    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46yamfud/)